# How to use regex in matches() to look for letters, dots, and apostrophe?

Tags: java, regex

In the following code, I tried many expressions to check if the string `str` has only letters, dots, or apostrophe by using `matches()` method.

However, it's not returning `true` for this string, for example, `one o'clock.` :

```
String str = "One o'clock.";
System.out.println(str.matches("[^a-zA-Z'. ]"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. your regex is using [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^...]`
2. your regex can match strings with only one character.

So use standard character class `[a-zA-Z'. ]` and to let your regex match strings one or more characters use `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
System.out.println(str.matches("[a-zA-Z'. ]+"));
```

Comment: Well defined, thanks! Just one more thing, to state the opposite of that regex, can I do this `"![a-zA-Z'. ]+"` ?

Comment: No `!` is not regex operator. Do you need to do it as regex? Can't you simply use negation on result of `matches()` like `System.out.println(!str.matches("[a-zA-Z'. ]+"));`?

Comment: Also it is not obvious what you mean by opposite. Is `"foo123"` opposite (notice that it can be partially matched by current regex)?

Comment: I want to use it with a replaceAll() method. So I have to use the negation of that regex or anything similar that gives the same result.

Comment: So you want to remove all characters except some predefined? In that case negated character class should be fine `replaced = original.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'. ]+","")`

Comment: I mean everything but letters, dots, or apostrophe. (the opposite of what you just provide)

Comment: Then as I said before negated character class should work fine. It will find all characters which are not `a-zA-Z'. ` and replace it with nothing (will remove them).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one `[\p{Alpha}\s'.]*`